# POST Request with JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to make a POST request using the jquery `$.ajax`. My problem is the data being sent is JSON. So i'm not sure exactly how to send it. I am using fiddler to record the HTTP request and this is what I got. `{"code":200,"user":"34522","questions":[{"35":"139"},{"55":"215"},{"28":"110"},{"88":"349"},{"127":"500"},{"148":"578"},{"125":"492"},{"218":"859"},{"258":"1019"},{"219":"862"}],"time":60}`. Under the webform of fiddler there is nothing there.
[image]

Here is the code I came up with and the response back is `Object {code: 500, error: "Invalid request"}`

```
var request = $.ajax({
      url: "http://website/api/post/",
      type: "POST",
      data: { 
        code : 200,
        user : 34522,
        questions : '[{"35":"139"},{"55":"215"},{"28":"110"},{"88":"349"},{"127":"500"},{"148":"578"},{"125":"492"},{"218":"859"},{"258":"1019"},{"219":"862"}]',
        time : 60
      },
      dataType: "json"
    });

    request.done(function( msg ) {
      console.log(msg);
    });

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
```

Comment: It literally says in your image: "Content-Type is 'application/json'; this Inspector supports 'x-www-form-urlencoded' only."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using JSON.stringify on your post data like this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://website/api/post/",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({ 
    code : 200,
    user : 34522,
    questions : [{"35":"139"},{"55":"215"},{"28":"110"},{"88":"349"},{"127":"500"},{"148":"578"},{"125":"492"},{"218":"859"},{"258":"1019"},{"219":"862"}],
    time : 60
  }),
  dataType: "json"
});
```

`JSON.stringify` will convert the current javascript object into a JSON string for posting. Also note removing the apostrophes from around the questions array.

Answer (score 0):

The dataType:json refers to the response I believe. So if the server response isn't valid json, you would see a 500 error.

Try to look at the 'network (chrome)' or 'net (firefoxl)' tab in firebug to inspect the response.

You could also try to change `dataType:json` to `dataType:text`